# spring boot RestController JSON serialization cost too much time

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am developing a restful service using latest version of spring boot.
Here is a RestController:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/table")
    public Iterable<Obsidian> getReactTable(@RequestParam Long orderId) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ArrayList<Obsidian> results = new ArrayList<Obsidian>();
            for (Obsidian obs : obsidianRepo.findByOrder(order)) {
                results.add(obs);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
//  Only cost about 300ms
//          System.out.println(end - start);
            return results;
        }
    }
```

the results list has about 500 Obsidians instances in total.

the Hibernate only cost me 300ms ,  and the JSON serialization (plus nio and web transfer) cost me 30 seconds!

What may cause Jackson be so slow?

btw: How I found it 30 seconds: I measure it in browser ajax.

Comment: btw, I can make sure that the jackson slows. Entity Obsidian has about 15 simple attributes,  When I use @JsonIgnore to ignore some field in the POJO Obsidian, it gets faster.

Comment: Do you use `lazy loading`? Are you sure that no extra calls to external systems are made during serialisation? Generally `Jackson` is fast when it serializes simple `POJO` model to `String`.

Comment: all attributes in POJO Obsidian are simple String or Long or Boolean, no ManyToMany, no OneToMany, no lazy loading.

Comment: I am considering using Gson to see if it's faster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Jackson is fast.

**Long answer:**

I have to say sorry, I made a big mistake. The POJO serialization is not that simple as I thought, it extends some base entity class, and the base class serialization is doing something slow in the database query.

If you come across the question, check your POJO carefully.

set show-sql=true will help you find out the problem.

**Old mistake:**

in order to prove that jackson is really slow, I add some code here:

```
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayList<Obsidian> results = new ArrayList<Obsidian>();
        for (Obsidian obs : obsidianRepo.findByOrder(order)) {
            results.add(obs);
            mapper.writeValueAsString(obs);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
```

as you can see, I manually call jackson com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper in the for loop to see how much time it cost, and the result is: 33247ms, which is exactly the time I measured in browser ajax.

```
@Test 
public void testJackson() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Obsidian obs = new Obsidian();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValueAsString(obs);
}
```

I also add a Test in JUnit Test, it cost 0.070s to complete.

as a Gson compare:

```
@Test 
public void testJackson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Obsidian obs = new Obsidian();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(obs);
}
```

Gson only cost 0.018s. (still too slow)

Comment: i cant see at where you record the "start"

Comment: probably it should be the time taken for entity loading, better to use a CPU profiler (JProfiler or Yourkit) and pin point the problem.

Comment: @hunter  I use spring boot RestController for a lot of web projects and never feel that Jackson can be slow on a not too long list, and today, one of my fellow says, hey, how can 500 records table (without server side pagination since I use react table this time) be so ridiculous slow. Now I will debug into the ObjectMapper and see how many instructions it runs to write a JSON string for one POJO.